# how to print out WHOLE list of dictionary values of txt file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the

```
exist = False while(exist == False):
try:
    name = input('Please enter a file name: ')
    myfile = open(name,'r')
    a = myfile.readline()
    b = myfile.readlines()
    count = len(b)
    exist = True
except:
    print('Error!', name, 'does not exist.')

myfile.close()

# converting input file into dict 
lst = list() for term in b:
    newterm = term.replace('\n','').split('\t')    #replacing with tab
    lst.append(newterm)

keylst = list()
vallst = list()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    keylst.append(lst[i][0])
    vallst.append(lst[i][1])

dict = {} 
for i in range(len(lst)):
    tempdict = {keylst[i]:vallst[i]}
    dict.update(tempdict)
```

Bunch of code here, user input and so on.

This code is how I formatted the table below.

```
print('There are', len(dict), 'terms in the new vocabulary list.')
lst = '{0:<5} - {1:>35}'.format(newterm[0], newterm[1])
print(lst)
```

here saving file

This gives me the output below:

```
while - Executes a block of code as long as its condition is true.
```

which prints out only last line/column of my .txt file, but what I want is whole dictionary to print out.
like this:

```
term    definition
break   Used to exit a for loop or a while loop1.
continue    Used to skip the current block, and return to the "for" or "while" statement
dictionary  A mutable associative array (or dictionary) of key and value pairs. 
float   An immutable floating point number.
immutable   Cannot be changed after its created.
int An immutable integer of unlimited magnitude.
pass    Needed to create an empty code block
set Unordered set, contains no duplicates
string  Can include numbers, letters, and various symbols and be enclosed by either double or single quotes
while   Executes a block of code as long as its condition is true.
```

I tried different ways but none of them worked. please help

Comment: Why `a = myfile.readline()`, but  `b = myfile.readlines()` ? readline***S***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing something weird
Instead of

```
> for i in range(len(lst)):
>     keylst.append(lst[i][0])
>     vallst.append(lst[i][1])
> 
> dict = {} for i in range(len(lst)):
>     tempdict = {keylst[i]:vallst[i]}
>     dict.update(tempdict)
```

just use
`my_dict=dict(lst)`
and don't create variable named `dict` for it shadows built-in function `dict`.
The second problem - you don't iterate over your dict, you just output data from newterm. And you need

```
for term, description in my_dict.items():
    print('{0:<5} - {1:>35}'. format(term, description))
```